# Custom CSS variables with Sass indexing technique confusion?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-variables

Here's a link to the code, its not too long, 54 lines + HTML:

https://codepen.io/Yonkai/pen/YrdNqE?editors=0100

The problem I'm having is I don't understand specifically how this line works, on line 22:

```
--m-ini: calc(var(--i, 0) - #{$p});
```

In the context, I don't know how the --i (index) custom CSS variable is being handled or accessing these indexes, how is each index being picked through each call in animation? (COMPILED FROM SASS):

```
.ball:nth-child(2) {
  --i: 1;
}
.ball:nth-child(3) {
  --i: 2;
}
.ball:nth-child(4) {
  --i: 3;
}
.ball:nth-child(5) {
  --i: 4;
}
.ball:nth-child(6) {
  --i: 5;
}
.ball:nth-child(7) {
  --i: 6;
}
.ball:nth-child(8) {
  --i: 7;
}
.ball:nth-child(9) {
  --i: 8;
}
.ball:nth-child(10) {
  --i: 9;
}
.ball:nth-child(11) {
  --i: 10;
}
.ball:nth-child(12) {
  --i: 11;
}
.ball:nth-child(13) {
  --i: 12;
}
.ball:nth-child(14) {
  --i: 13;
}
.ball:nth-child(15) {
  --i: 14;
}
.ball:nth-child(16) {
  --i: 15;
}
```

I believe this has to do with something unrelated to the functionality of calc() or var() and custom variables, but I'm honestly dumbfounded.

This is based on someones else code and they have a youtube video but its not much help.

Answer (score 0):

Line 22 is a custom variable `--m-ini`. `--i` is another custom variable, it's value is being set on line 44. Line 41 is the a declaration for iteration, where `$i` is each iteration from 1 to 16, `--i` is being set to `$i`.

Comment: Okay, so what does the `--i` in `--m-ini: calc(var(--i, 0) - #{$p});` refer to if `--i` is being set multiple times? I know `0` is the deafult value for when nothing is there. It's very likely i'm misunderstanding this whole setup.

Comment: `--i` isn't defined in the `--m-ini` declaration, so the default value `0` is being used. `--i` is being updated in the iteration. So each ball, `nth-child` has a different value for `--i`, the iteration number, which is used in the `state` mixin `translate` and `scale` functions.